# Automatic reboot using cron

Tags: cron, reboot

I want to reboot a Raspberry Pi at every minute but my cronjob syntax doesn't work:

```
# */1 * * * * reboot
```

Comment: Please don't add code as pictures especially if it's a oneliner this only proves lazyness

Comment: Rebooting your raspberry pi every minute is not wise... why would you even want to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your line is commented out so never performed 
    
   -> delete the `#` at the start
2. It should be `* * * * *` for every minute
3. (Thanks to @Rinzwind)
   `reboot` does not work
   It has to be 
   `systemctl reboot -i`

So in the end in your file there should be the line

```
* * * * * systemctl reboot -i
```

`-i` here stands for ignore-inhibitors. Some programs put this inhibitors lock to prevent dataloss so you wouldn't reboot but get a note in the command line.

This should do the trick

**Note:**
Not letting unmentioned here that this doesn't seem a smart idea to me ... Why do you want that? And make sure you are able to revert this before your system reboots again when you don't want this anymore ;)

Comment: Well it has a lot to do with the question.. but I see and accept what you mean.

Comment: This is correct, but the answer is incomplete. Usually `reboot` command needs 'sudo' rights, so this must be written in root's crontab - `sudo crontab -e`, or in `/etc/crontab` or somewhere in `/etc/cron.d/`. It is also recommended to use the fill path to the program within crontab, so we can write `which reboot` to find it...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the image already shows the file edited by `sudo crontab -e` .. the question is incomplete in information though. Usually those are already performed with root permissions

Comment: @pa4080 nope. reboot does not But the command is wrong. `systemctl reboot -i` is the command to use.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks didn't know that. Actually for certain reason never tried this before until I came home now but you are right. Edited my answer

Comment: I'm really curious as to why someone would want to do this. Hardware stress test? See how components stand up to minutely reboots for a few weeks? Uhh, and that's about all I can come up with. A mean prank on a friend or coworker's system maybe but that seems cruel.

Comment: I am guessing the latter.